# External Content - Error on URL

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to add som external content so i can load external HTML to my newsletter sending.

The problem I found is that some URL gives me error when I try to configure it.

Same content works for a URL but not for another one.

Is there any limitation or any requirement for that to work properly?